# content TEXT from microsoft office to HTML

Tags: java, html, ms-office, converters

I have an HTML wysiwyg in my web application, and my users copy/paste contents from Microsoft Office.

I need a Java method to convert an office content (TEXT STRING) to html content.

i wrote thie code

```
value = value.replaceAll("(?s)<[^>]*>(\\s*<[^>]*>)*", " ").replaceAll("\n\r", " ").replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll("\r", " ");
value = value.replaceAll("<xml>.*?</xml>", " ").replaceAll("<style>.*?</style>", " ").replaceAll("\n\r", "<br />").replaceAll("\n", "<br />").replaceAll("\r", "<br />").replace("id=" , "OldId=");
```

but this code doesn't give me the correct text.

PS:
this web site does exactly what I need to do
http://word2cleanhtml.com/

Comment: Please provide samples of inputs, current results and expected results. Otherwise, it's going to be hard to guess what your issue really is.

Comment: The website that you link to says they're in the process of making an API. So I say, have some patience.